# Cosa significa "gnorco"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Agnello non doveva scapparsene, doveva confidarsi con lui, lui li avrebbe aiutati, lui l’avrebbe tirata fuori, avrebbe impedito a quelle chiazzère **gnorche** di portarla alla Children’s Society, li mandava sotto agli alberi pizzuti quelli che volevano male ad Agnello che era come suo padre e a Vita che era la sua piccola sorella.

Sul [vocabolario napoletano-italiano di Giuseppe Giacco](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf) ho trovato che "chiazzèra" significa "piazzaiòla" (si tratta di un aggettivo, ma penso che nel testo sia sostantivato). Non sono però riuscita a trovare il termine "gnorco" su nessun dizionario italiano e neanche su questo vocabolario né sul [*Lessico e Letteratura del Dialetto Napoletano*](https://independent.academia.edu/SalvatoreArgenziano) di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?